# Unresolved reference to KFunctionN

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am trying to create function references in Kotlin, my understanding is I should be able to access the generated `KFunctionN` interfaces at compile time, but I am getting an 'Unresolved reference' compilation error for `KFunction1<T, R>`.

For example:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any, reified R : Any> passFn(someFn: KFunction1<T, R>) {
    //consume someFn
}
```

I have kotlin-reflect on the class path and working fine. Any ideas what I am missing?

I am using Kotlin 1.3.21 and IntelliJ 2018.3.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like an IDE issue, I have typed the import the `import kotlin.reflect.KFunction1` and compiler error goes away.

However, if you add an expression/statement which returns a `KFunction1` type and explicitly declare the type, the Intellij imports it correctly. For example;

```
"\\s+".toRegex()::matches
```

Can be extracted as

```
val kFunction1: KFunction1<@ParameterName(name = "input") CharSequence, Boolean> = "\\s+".toRegex()::matches
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get a KFunction1 from an anonymous lambda?

Comment: Answering my own question - there is an experimental API available that will do this: `fun <R> Function<R>.reflect(): KFunction<R>?`

Comment: Okay. Good findings.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, very simple fix for this - you need to manually add the KFunctionN import, IntelliJ won't resolve it automatically.